# Is there a shell command that will kill all background tail processes

Tags: bash, kill, pid

If I run a script that starts several processes with the `&` like

```
tail -f log file1 &
tail -f log file2 &
```

How can i shut them all down at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to background jobs in your current shell with the `%1`, `%2`, ... idioms.

To my knowledge there's no such thing as a catch all; there's no `%*` or an equivalent.

But you could shortcut with

```
kill %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8
```

Which would kill the first eight background processes still running in your current shell. That may or may not be a `tail`.

Be careful whom you kill ;-)

If you have full control of the background processes this might be a safe bet for you. Since you mention that you want to do this from a shell script, and if the `tail`s are the only background processes, then this is straightforward. Just make sure your shell script starts a subshell, so that it never affects the background processes of an interactive shell. For instance you could start your script with

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

and set execute permission bits on the script and always call the script by name. In other words, you should not `source script_file` that script.

On the other hand, [jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252649/923794) to save the pids (process ids) of any process you are starting is a much more safe way of killing other processes.

Answer (score 13):

You can kill all tail commands by
`killall tail`

Comment: thats the answer i was hopin for!

Comment: That's it. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 5):

`killall tail` should do the trick but it will also close any other tail processes you have running.

Answer (score 4):

"remember" the child pids.

```
tail -f logfile1 & 
pid1=$!

tail -f logfile2 &
pid2=$!

kill $pid1 $pid2
```

Obviously, you would not issue an immediate kill like that in your real script. You would probably really want to wait for the child processes instead.  But this does what you asked